# Element Created by Javascript is not visually visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

So, recently I made a project where the Javascript just create an element and getting the data from Firebase Firestore database then append it to the body of HTML. This consist of a div which act as the box container with `object.className`, h4 act as title, some p as texts. But, all of those elements I've added isn't visible on the webpage. But surprisingly, if I open the Inspect element, and call `console.log(object)` of one of the object, they will show up HTML tag element that exactly what I want and when I hover it, it will show up a highlighted area in the webpage that sized exactly what I want. But, still not visually visible. Actually, in the HTML document, I've added some boxes and element before the element from Javascript, and if I add some new element from the HTML, the element from Javascript is pushed after the newly added element from HTML. So, can someone help me? I'm a newbie in this field. Thank you.

> 1.) Part of the HTML Element (The Firebase is well set-up here)

```
<body>
<div class="big-container">
    <div class="title">
        <span class="title-text">Kompor</span>
    </div>
    <nav id="wrapper">
        <!-- ONE DIV CALLED "IMPORTANT" is necessary for the last box visible -->
        <div onclick="" class="box">
            <h4 class="title-box">Rinnai 522-E</h4>
            <p class="tc-1">HB</p>
            <p class="tc-2">313.000</p>
            <p class="tc-3">HJ</p>
            <p class="tc-4">345.000</p>
        </div>
        <div onclick="" class="box 2">
            <h4 class="title-box">Rinnai 522-A</h4>
            <p class="tc-1">HB</p>
            <p class="tc-2">313.000</p>
            <p class="tc-3">HJ</p>
            <p class="tc-4">345.000</p>
        </div>
        <div onclick="" class="box">
            <h4 class="title-box">Rinnai 522-E</h4>
            <p class="tc-1">HB</p>
            <p class="tc-2">313.000</p>
            <p class="tc-3">HJ</p>
            <p class="tc-4">345.000</p>
        </div>
        <div onclick="" class="box">
            <h4 class="title-box">Rinnai 522-E</h4>
            <p class="tc-1">HB</p>
            <p class="tc-2">313.000</p>
            <p class="tc-3">HJ</p>
            <p class="tc-4">345.000</p>
        </div>
        <div onclick="" class="box">
            <h4 class="title-box">Rinnai 522-E</h4>
            <p class="tc-1">HB</p>
            <p class="tc-2">313.000</p>
            <p class="tc-3">HJ</p>
            <p class="tc-4">345.000</p>
        </div>
        <div onclick="" class="box">
            <h4 class="title-box">Rinnai 522-E</h4>
            <p class="tc-1">HB</p>
            <p class="tc-2">313.000</p>
            <p class="tc-3">HJ</p>
            <p class="tc-4">345.000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="important"></div>  
    </nav>
</div>
```

> 2.) JS

```
//DOMstart
const docTarget = document.querySelector('#wrapper');

function insertDoc(doc){
        //creation
        let box = document.createElement('div');
        let header = document.createElement('h4');
        let hargaBeli = document.createElement('p');
        let p2 = document.createElement('p');
        let hargaJual = document.createElement('p');
        let p4 = document.createElement('p');
    //insertion

    header.textContent = doc.data().name;
    hargaBeli.innerHTML = "HB";
    p2.textContent = doc.data().HB;
    hargaJual.innerHTML = "HJ";
    p4.textContent = doc.data().HJ;

    console.log(box);
    console.log(header);
    console.log(hargaBeli);
    console.log(p2);
    console.log(hargaJual);
    console.log(p4);

    //naming
    box.classname = "box";
    header.className = "title-box";
    hargaBeli.className = "tc-1";
    p2.className = "tc-2";
    hargaJual.className = "tc-3";
    p4.className = "tc-4";

    //box-naming plus deletion ops
    var hitung = 1;
    hitung++;
    console.log(hitung);
    box.className = "box " + hitung;
    box.onclick = function(){
                        if (confirm('Apa kamu yakin mau menghapus produk ini?')) {
                            this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
                        } else {
                        console.log('Tidak jadi menghapus produk.');
                        }
    }

    //appending...
    box.appendChild(header);
    box.appendChild(hargaJual);
    box.appendChild(p2);
    box.appendChild(hargaBeli);
    box.appendChild(p4);
    docTarget.appendChild(box); 
    console.log(box.className + "Creation Tracker"); //detection
}

//get doc

var doc;
db.collection('Product').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        insertDoc(doc);
    })
})
```

The CSS is connected well and as you can see working well with those elements from HTML document.

Comment: I assume this is something to do with firebase (which it might be nice to add as a tag on your question). Is that why 'db' is not defined?

Comment: db is defined in the HTML document (in a part that not included above)

Answer (score 0):

As I tried your HTML and javascript code on jsbin, I see that it worked well. The problem is your variable `doc`, you might add console.log to get the variable again to see why, or you can paste your data structure for further debug.

https://jsbin.com/jeyamoqabu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I've just tried that and it comes like this picture in https://ibb.co/nBxTTrq.

Comment: @AndreasNotokusumo How about `doc.data()`?

Comment: It will show an "Object" containing some info from my database

Comment: It's weird, would you try to use some random string for your textContent?

Comment: I just did, nothing different happen

Comment: Did my workaround in jsbin link above work as expected?